# How to copy column from user-chosen source workbook\worksheet\column to active target workbook\worksheet\column?

Tags: excel, vba

Source column contains a string in each cell. There are 4000+ cells. These need to be copied and pasted into a worksheet of the active (one that invoked the macro) workbook. Source workbook should be selected by the user using a search/browse pop-up box.

The below code does something close to my intended goal, but the directory as you see is static which is unacceptable. Maximum flexibility should be had with user choosing the source file manually. Furthermore I want to prevent the file path from becoming obsolete every time folders/files get renamed/shifted. Something tell me `Application.GetOpenFilename()` should be used, but how to correctly implement it?

Having little experience with the VBA, my attempts to mod this macro failed, so I'm asking for your advice on this matter. Again, the below  code works well, but it's not flexible enough to be practical.

Edit: the problem is solved. See the final working code.

```
'MACRO TO READ-IN EXTERNAL EXCEL FILE FROM WHICH JOB NO.'S ARE EXTRACTED INTO USERFORM
Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()
    'IN CASE OF ERROR SEND TO ERROR FUNCTION
    On Error GoTo ErrHandler
    
    'PREVENT OPENED EXCEL SOURCE FILE FROM SHOWING TO USER
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    
    'OPEN SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE"
    Dim SrcName As String
    Dim src As Workbook
    SrcName = Application.GetOpenFilename()
    Set src = Workbooks.Open(SrcName, True, True)
    
    'GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK
    Dim iTotalRows As Integer
    iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A1:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count
    
    'COPY DATA FROM SOURCE WORKBOOK  -> DESTINATION WORKBOOK
    Dim iCnt As Integer     '(COUNTER)
    For iCnt = 1 To iTotalRows
        Worksheets("Test_File_8").Range("B" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula
    Next iCnt

    'CLOSE THE SOURCE WORKBOOK FILE
    src.Close False 'FALSE = DONT SAVE THE SOURCE FILE
    Set src = Nothing  'FLUSH DATA

    'ERROR FUNCTION
    ErrHandler:
        Application.EnableEvents = True
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

See my changes below. I added two variables `X` and `strSrc`. `X` is a variant that is used to loop through `.SelectedItems` and `strSrc` is that string that ultimately holds the path.

```
    Sub ReadDataFromCloseFile()

    'Set variable to hold workbook path and workbook path string
       Dim X as Variant
       Dim strSrc as String

       With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
          .InitialFileName = "" ' You can provide a base path here
          .Title = "Select file."
          .AllowMultiSelect = False
          If .Show = -1 Then
              For Each X In .SelectedItems
                  strSrc = X
                  Exit For
              Next X
          End If
       End With

    'IN CASE OF ERROR SEND TO ERROR FUNCTION
        'On Error GoTo ErrHandler

    'PREVENT OPENED EXCEL SOURCE FILE FROM SHOWING TO USER
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'OPEN SOURCE EXCEL WORKBOOK IN "READ ONLY MODE"
        Dim src As Workbook
        Set src = Workbooks.Open(strSrc, True, True)

    'GET THE TOTAL ROWS FROM THE SOURCE WORKBOOK
        Dim iTotalRows As Integer
        iTotalRows = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A1:A" & src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).Rows.Count

    'COPY DATA FROM SOURCE WORKBOOK  -> DESTINATION WORKBOOK
            Dim iCnt As Integer     '(COUNTER)
            For iCnt = 1 To iTotalRows
                src.Worksheets("Test_File_8").Range("B" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula
            Next iCnt

    'CLOSE THE SOURCE WORKBOOK FILE
        src.Close False             'FALSE = DONT SAVE THE SOURCE FILE
        Set src = Nothing           'FLUSH DATA

    'ERROR FUNCTION
     ErrHandler: Application.EnableEvents = True Application.ScreenUpdating = True End Sub

    'MACRO TO READ-IN EXTERNAL EXCEL FILE FROM WHICH JOB NO.'S ARE EXTRACTED INTO USERFORM
```

Comment: Kyle, thanks for such a fast response! Sadly the code does not work. What happens is that the source workbook gets opened and brought to forefront of my screen as it usually does when code is broken. No error message is given by VBA Editor.

Comment: Does the code open the desired workbook and copy/paste the code?

Comment: Source workbook opens and stays open. No code is copied/pasted into target workbook. No VBA Editor errors.

Comment: See my change. I bet you had an error, but your error handler covered it up. You should never develop with an error handler.

Comment: You are right. ErrHandler was suppressing Error 9 which now that you have commented it out appears. Other than this, source workbook appears on screen. Nothing is copies/pasted to target. Error 9 flags this line as problematic: " src.Worksheets("Test_File_8").Range("B" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula "

Comment: Do those two worksheets exist in the workbook `src` and is that what you are trying to accomplish? you have given little guidance on your actual intended output, so I gave you code that will get you most the way there? have you done anything except paste my code in and then say it didn't work?

Comment: The source and target worksheets live in different worksheets. No, I am trying to copy/paste an entire block of cells from statically-named target sheet, where the block is dynamic and always growing. Intended output is a 1:1 copy from target to source. Copying omits column header.

Comment: Then I am unable to help with the information provided.

Comment: No worries. Thanks for trying!

Comment: If you can provide accurate information, I would be able to help. You should read this [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I read the article and agree. Not sure what other details I am missing. The program is completed short of getting a user to hand-pick the file. Your mod attempted to integrate this feature but resulted in Error 9. Program worked 100% before then. Not sure how to go about debugging your addition. And, how does .SelectedItems relate to my code below comment 'COPY DATA FROM SOURCE WORKBOOK ? What does .Show=-1 do?

Comment: Copy and paste action is taken care of this: " src.Worksheets("Test_File_8").Range("B" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula = src.Worksheets("PROJECT LIST").Range("A" & (iCnt + 1)).Formula ". How to have your code pass on the opened source file to my copy/paste code? I just need the go-between programming.

Comment: Cell in source column have values such as 12345 and 12345B. There are 4000+ of them and they are not sorted. They live in column range A2:A. A since the column length is a function of time.

Comment: In your question, you make it seem as though your issue was getting the user input piece to work, but the code you posted didn't do what you wanted at all. Now the user input works, so I would need to know which cells to copy, what the worksheet name is that they are housed in and where you would like them to be copied. I will add more color to what the code is doing later.

Comment: To answer your questions: 1) Cells to be copied are A2:A, 2) Target worksheet name is "test10c" and source worksheet name is "master_db6", 3) Want to copy them into target worksheet "test10c". Also, 4) Source worksheet is "PROJECT LIST". 5) Target worksheet is "Lookup Lists".

Comment: In one attempt "Application.GetOpenFilename()" worked to bring in source file but I got stuck at this point. Didn't know how to pull cells out of it and how to throw them into target file.